# node-webkit in app purchase flow

Tags: in-app-purchase, node-webkit, mac-app-store

I am porting a webapp to be used on OSX using node-webkit. Our app also has a premium plan (subscription).

How would I trigger the a in app purchase flow from within js code?

Comment: I think there is no way to do that, since node-webkit is built on Chromium and node only, no Apple framework is linked to it. If your users can subscribe online then you can recognize their subscriptions inside the app and save 30% by not sharing with Apple

Comment: a node module that is binded to StoreKit can do the trick. Or in a simple way have a macappstore:// url instead of stripe/paypal widget.

Comment: "node module that is binded to StoreKit can do the trick" -- I think, such a module should be compiled separately, being a binary module. Yet you will have to use same bundle name, same signatures, etc. for its payment transaction to be recognized by Apple as coming from the "parent" app.